# Checking the existence of a file using relative path

Tags: c#

What is the best way to check the  existence of a file using relative path.

I've used the following  method but it returns false despite the fact that file is existing.

```
 bool a = File.Exists("/images/Customswipe_a.png");
```

Comment: relative to execution path? Also, if this is not web, why are you using `/` insteaed of `\\`

Comment: Did you by chance missed "asp.net" tag and need Server.MapPath instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's not a relative path.  You need to leave off the first `/` otherwise it will be interpreted as being rooted (i.e. C:/images...)

Comment: It is relative path technically, just relative to current drive.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Maybe technically, yes.  But why distinguish between absolute and relative paths if they're all relative to something anyway?

Comment: My definition is "if path refers to the same file irrespective of environment configuration" (also it is different from `Path.IsPathRooted` which is another way to look at it). I have hard time calling path "\p\f.txt" absolute as it can refer to "c:\p\f.txt" or "d:\p\f.txt" depending on current path... "c:\path\file.txt" or "\\server\path\file.txt" look much more absolute to me.

Answer (score 10):

I guess that you are running this code in asp.net application, thats why you get false.

In asp.net you should use `Server.MapPath("/images/Customswipe_a.png")` to get "correct" path (relative to the web application root directory). Otherwise you get path  local to the webserver executable (IIS/WEBDAV/..name any other).

Answer (score 6):

The relative path is relative to the current working directory. It may not be the application directory. Call **GetCurrentDirectory()** to check the actual path you are testing.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to define what your file is relative to

- Your application main assembly?
- Current directory?
- Application data directory?
- name it...

In each of these cases I'd suggest you to convert it into an absolute path by `Path.Combine` method:

```
public static readonly string AppRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

...

//calling with a '/' heading makes the path absolute so I removed it
var fullPath = Path.Combine(AppRoot, "images/Customswipe_a.png");
var exists = File.Exists(fullPath);
```

This way you can guarantee where you are looking for. Even the Open/Save file dialogs may change your current directory. So, calling `File.Exists` without full path is usually a wrong decision.

Answer (score 3):

You can test this path with System.IO.DirectoryInfo:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("/images/Customswipe_a.png");
string absoluteFullPath = info.FullName;
```

As Mike Park correctly answered this path is likely to be  (i.e. C:/images...)

Answer (score 1):

The relative path, is a **relative** to something. 
In this API, it will, according to the documentation [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx):

> Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current
>   working directory.

So everything here is depends what is *CurrentDirectoty* at the moment of execution of this query.

Plus, your path is not valid Desktop path (I assume you pick it from some web file, or knowledge). To understand if specified path contains not valid characters use [GetInvalidCharacters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx) function.

In your specific case it would be enough to use `@"\images\Customswipe_a.png"`.

Comment: It is valid for .Net APIs, unusual to use "/" instead of "\", but valid. And `Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Contains('/')` does not report "/" as invalid...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I don't say for .NET API, I say like Desktop application path.

Answer (score 0):

The path is relative to the location of your binary file.  In the case of a visual studio project, this would be `%PROJECTDIR%/bin/(RELEASE||DEBUG)/`

What I would do is put the filesystem root in a config file, and use that for your relative path.

Answer (score 0):

In a WinForms application you can get the directory of the exe file with

```
string directory =
    Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Another solution uses Reflection

```
string directory =
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of **.NET Core 3.1**, this works:

Use dependency injection to include service `IWebHostEnvironment`

```
private IWebHostEnvironment Env;

public MyController (IWebHostEnvironment env){
    Env = env;
}
```

Then use it to get path to root of app with `Env.ContentRootPath`

And combine it all:

```
var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(Env.ContentRootPath, "images", "some-file.png");
```