# Test for a json file in the bin folder

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a simple project that uses a Json file to hold some file paths and other project variabled, which is stored in the output bin of my project at run time.

I have a circumstance  where I want to test if the json file exists before I try and read it, however IO.File.Exist method requires a path to test and that would include the bin folder such as

```
...\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BackupCopyGrpSyspro\BackupCopyGrpSyspro\bin\Debug
```

What I am concerned about is after deployment the file to test would not be my local drive but the location I deploy to.

How can I do this test for the deployed location which I might not know in advance ?

Also I have a scope problem with **readProjectSettings** if I declare it in the if block. How do over come this, put the assignment `Settings.decProp1 = readProjectSettings.decProp1;` (There are sixteen properties to assign, into a helper method or is there a simpler way?

```
 string fileName ="ProjectSettings.Json";
        string targetPath =@"C:\Users\ianwheeler\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BackupCopyGrpSyspro\BackupCopyGrpSyspro\bin\Debug\";
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(sourceFile))
        {
            var readProjectSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectSettings>(File.ReadAllText("ProjectSettings.json"));
        }
        else
        {
            var readProjectSettings = new ProjectSettings();
        }

        Settings.decProp1 = readProjectSettings.decProp1;
```

Comment: make the file path or part of it as a parameter to your method.

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941908/checking-the-existence-of-a-file-using-relative-path

Comment: @TimBourguignon yes I can see that except I did not know to look for "relavite path" - sorry. I also have the scope issue as well in the question

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your scope problem. You just need to declare your variable outside the "if" block and initialize it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combined my two comments above. A simple bin path should be relative (unless you are working in Web in which case you will have to get the applicationPath and concatenate it to the filepath). As for the scope of your `readProjectSettings`, simply declare it out of the `if` block. Thus this should more or less work...

```
string fileName ="ProjectSettings.Json";
ProjectSettings readProjectSettings;

if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
    readProjectSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectSettings>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
}
else
{
    readProjectSettings = new ProjectSettings();
}

Settings.decProp1 = readProjectSettings.decProp1;
```

Comment: Thank you when I tried to declare the readProjectSettings I was using a "var" as type and hence getting an error because I was not setting aswell. Many Thanks

Comment: Oh yes, `var` is only a shortcut to not have to write a longer Type, but it needs to be defined at compile time. If you simply define `var someVariable;` the compiler has no way to know what you meant, hence the compile error.